# React Native with expo and monorepo import error

Tags: react-native, expo, nestjs, expo-router, nx-monorepo

I am using monorepo with nestjs and react native and trying to share zod types from nestjs zod lib but this react native app is having issues starting up, but at the same time nest js project is able to resolve everything and run properly here is the error

```js
Unable to resolve module nestjs-zod/z from /Users/disolaterx/guawaa/packages/common/dist/index.js: nestjs-zod/z could not be found within the project or in these directories:
../../node_modules
node_modules
../../node_modules
57 | // src/dto/login.dto.ts
58 | var import_nestjs_zod = require("nestjs-zod");

> 59 | var import_z = require("nestjs-zod/z");
> |                         ^
> 60 | var loginSchema = import_z.z.object({
> 61 |   email: import_z.z.string(),
> 62 |   password: import_z.z.string()

RCTFatal
\__28-\[RCTCxxBridge handleError:\]\_block_invoke
\_dispatch_call_block_and_release
\_dispatch_client_callout
\_dispatch_main_queue_drain
\_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
\__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
\-\[UIApplication \_run\]
UIApplicationMain
main
start_sim
0x0
0x0
```

Here is the metro config

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

// Find the project and workspace directories
const projectRoot = __dirname;
// This can be replaced with `find-yarn-workspace-root`
const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(projectRoot, '../..');

const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot);

// 1. Watch all files within the monorepo
config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot];
// 2. Let Metro know where to resolve packages and in what order
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
  path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
  path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules'),
];

// 3. Force Metro to resolve (sub)dependencies only from the `nodeModulesPaths`
// config.resolver.disableHierarchicalLookup = true;

module.exports = config;
```

this should resolve the nestjs-zod/z and just start the app instead of crashing